# chaining az calls in a powershell script

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm trying to build a script that sets up my Azure environment, but passing information from one call to the next is proving to be tricky. I'm not sure how to treat the data returned as an object.

```
# az network public-ip create  output (truncated)
#{
#  "publicIp": {
#    "ipAddress": "1.1.1.1",
#  }
#}
$staticIpCreate = (az network public-ip create --resource-group mygroup --name myipname --allocation-method static | ConvertFrom-Json)
$staticIp = ($staticIpCreate | Select-Object ipAddress)
Write-Host "Static Ip :$($staticIp)"
```

Comment: Have you tried `(az .... ) | Convert-FromJson`?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are combine Azure CLI and Powershell?

Comment: that was it :)

the reason I'm using both is because I have used powershell before; if there is a script that is better I'd be open to hear it.

Comment: I would just write the script in native Powershell (vs. embedding Azure CLI in Powershell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to combine them, here is PowerShell command to achieve the samething

```
$PIP = New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -AllocationMethod Static -ResourceGroupName DDemo -Location Westus2 -Name DDemoIPTest
Write-Host "Static IP:" $PIP.IpAddress
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7w1Am.png)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7w1Am.png]

Answer (score 0):

from jessehouwing's comment

```
Write-Debug "////// static ip"
$staticIpCreate = az network public-ip create --resource-group mygroup --name myipname --allocation-method static | ConvertFrom-Json
$staticIp = $staticIpCreate.publicIp.ipAddress
Write-Host "Static Ip :$($staticIp)"
```